# Erro ao realizar um max(sum())

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Estou tentando resolver o problema para achar o estado com o maior numero de cidades que comecem com santo/santa. 
Para isso realizei essa view:

```
CREATE VIEW SANT AS ( 
SELECT E.NOME ESTADOS, M.NOME CIDADES, COUNT('CIDADES') AS CNT FROM ESTADO E, MUNICIPIO M 
WHERE E.CODESTADO = M.CODESTADO
AND M.NOME LIKE 'Santa%' OR M.NOME LIKE 'Santo%' 
GROUP BY M.NOME, E.NOME
);
```

após isso, tenho que realizar a soma com count e tirar o valor maximo obtido. mas quando faço:

```
select estados, sum(cnt) as soma from sant
where soma = (select max('soma') from sant)
group by estados
```

da erro pois não é encontrada a soma.... 
e quando faço

```
select estados, sum(cnt) as soma from sant
where cnt= (select max(cnt) from sant)
group by estados
```

o valor retornado é  8 para todos os estados.

consegui resolver a questão com mais uma view e um select, porém sei que se realizar apenas um select alinhado seria mais facil o banco de dados teria que gastar um custo menor. A questão é como eu poderia fazer isso?

segue abaixo como cheguei a resolução.

```
CREATE VIEW SOMA_SANT AS ( 
SELECT ESTADOS, SUM(CNT) SOMA FROM SANT 
GROUP BY ESTADOS
); 

SELECT ESTADOS  FROM SOMA_SANT 
WHERE SOMA = (SELECT MAX(SOMA) FROM SOMA_SANT)
```

Comment: Select * from sant order by cnt desc , a view já totaliza.

Comment: Assim  retorna a quantidade de cidades com o esse nome por estado. por ex: santa inês no tocantins tem 4. mas eu quero o estado com o maior número de cidades com esses nomes de santo. por isso preciso realizar o sum por estado e depois tirar o max.

Comment: Tire o M.NOME CIDADES da view , tente assim.

Comment: Segue contando do mesmo jeito

Comment: CREATE VIEW SANT AS ( 
SELECT E.NOME ESTADOS, COUNT('CIDADES') AS CNT FROM ESTADO E, MUNICIPIO M 
WHERE E.CODESTADO = M.CODESTADO
AND M.NOME LIKE 'Santa%' OR M.NOME LIKE 'Santo%' 
GROUP BY E.NOME
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Vinicius tudo bem? Podemos resolver isso de uma forma mais simples mas também tenho uma observação sobre a montagem da sua view:
Tenha cuidado com a mistura de `AND` e `OR`. Sempre que for utilizá-los em conjunto, opte por adicionar **parênteses** onde existir `OR`. Veja como ficaria seu WHERE:

```
WHERE E.CODESTADO = M.CODESTADO AND (M.NOME LIKE 'Santa%' OR M.NOME LIKE '%Santo%')
```

Sobre sua pergunta, podemos resolver com uma query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTDE, A.NOME AS NOMEESTADO FROM
  ESTADO AS A
  JOIN MUNICIPIO AS B ON B.CODESTADO = A.CODESTADO
WHERE B.NOME LIKE '%SANTO%' OR B.NOME LIKE '%SANTA%'
GROUP BY A.NOME --AGRUPANDO POR NOME PARA REALIZAR A CONTAGEM CORRETAMENTE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC --COMO TEMOS OS REGISTROS AGRUPADOS, PODEMOS ORDENAR POR AQUI
LIMIT 1 --CASO QUEIRA RETORNAR TODOS OS REGISTROS, REMOVA ESTE CÓDIGO
```

Código que utilizei para testar: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f0803/2